# Why does the intellij formatter append a blank line after embedded script?

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, formatter

For example, HTML that looks like this:

```
<script>
    var hello;
</script>
```

Becomes this after formatting a few times (**`Code`** > **`Reformat code...`**):

```
<script>
    var hello;



</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps, he believes that you write more :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with te same code. Try to explore your Javascript or HTML Code Style in Settings.

Comment: What happens if your code looks like this:  <script>var hello;</script> ? That is, no carriage returns.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? Are people just trying to be stupid or what? The same issue was happening to me and this question and answer have helped me. And I see this has been viewed 106 times already, so it must have helped somebody else. +1, man, and don't mind the retards

Answer (score 28):

I still don't know *why* the extra line is being added but I found a way to stop it.

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `HTML` > `Other` > `Keep white spaces inside:` > Then add `script`

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me, too.  I had the problem with the `<script>` and the `<style>` tag.  I think jetbrains might want to take a look at this.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: And they still have the problem 5 years later.. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: It works just fine! Incredible how I am commenting a 2015 post in 2020!